# Change Hadoop version for Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop

How can I set a Hadoop version for the Spark application without submitting a jar and defining specific Hadoop binary? And is it even possible?
I am just not really sure how can Hadoop version be changed while submitting Spark application.

Something like this does not work:

```
  val sparkSession = SparkSession
    .builder
    .master("local[*]")
    .appName("SparkJobHDFSApp")
    .getOrCreate()
  sparkSession.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("hadoop.common.configuration.version", "2.7.4")
```

Comment: You can not. You must use compatible with  Hadoop version for spark.
Why do you want to change hadoop version ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can't be. The Spark Master and Workers each have their own Hadoop JARs on the classpath with which your own application must be compatible with

Comment: Thanks. But how can I check Spark Hadoop version then? Only in dependent Spark libraries?

Comment: As far as I know, the latest Spark is only tested against Hadoop 2.7 (as listed on their downloads page). Anything else, it must be manually compiled against